# Visual Studio 2019 React Typescript Too many errors when adding CRA v4 app as SPA to a WEB project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, single-page-application

Here is how I got into this mess.

Created a React-Redux ASP NET CORE 5 project from the template.

[image: React Redux Template]

This version was completely outdated and I didn't want to clean up to basic so what I did was, delete the entire `ClientApp` folder, and Created a new react app using CRA with `npx create-react-app clientapp --template typescript`

Now This generated a working react app which starts fine with `npm start`. However, when I open the project in Visual studio, I am bombarded with so many errors.

[image: VS 2019 intellisense errors from typescript react]

I have tried almost all possible solutions I could find, I have set `skipLibCheck : true` in tsconfig.json , below

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ESNext",
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "noEmit": true,

        "jsx": "react-jsx"
    },
    "include": ["src"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "typings"]
}
```

I have also Added Typescript 4.1.2 Nuget package to my project. that didn't help, Visual Studio says `Using Typescript 4.1 for Intellisense` but still I get all these intellisense errors.

This is my `package.json` which was generated by CRA (and I added some eslint plugins, thats it)

```json
{
  "name": "clientapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.21",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I managed to dig in and solve this,

1. Using typescript react SPA is just asking my .net app to run npm commands and nothing else.
2. Typescript NuGet Package is used for intellisense in Visual studio.
3. Typescript NuGet package doesn't read the `tsconfig.json` file at all. It takes values from the proj config which has its own section of settings.
4. Even if your react app builds fine from command line since VS 2019 uses typescript nuget pkg for intellisense (it is not used for build at all, npm script is run for the build and dev) so you need to match the general `tsconfig.json` with configuration matching  from https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options-in-msbuild.html
5. So my config looked like this.

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
        <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
        <TypeScriptJSXEmit>React</TypeScriptJSXEmit>
        <TypeScriptModuleKind>CommonJS</TypeScriptModuleKind>
        <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>True</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
        <TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>False</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
        <TypeScriptRemoveComments>False</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
        <TypeScriptESModuleInterop>True</TypeScriptESModuleInterop>
        <TypeScriptOutFile />
        <TypeScriptAllowSyntheticDefaultImports>True</TypeScriptAllowSyntheticDefaultImports>
        <TypeScriptOutDir />
        <TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>False</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>
        <TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>True</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
        <TypeScriptSourceMap>True</TypeScriptSourceMap>
        <TypeScriptMapRoot />
        <TypeScriptSourceRoot />
    </PropertyGroup>
```

6. Also after you add the typescript Nuget Package, it automatically included the `node_modules` in the project again, so you have to exclude it again manually or add

```xml
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Remove="ClientApp\.vscode\**" />
        <EmbeddedResource Remove="ClientApp\.vscode\**" />
        <TypeScriptCompile Remove="ClientApp\.vscode\**" />
        <TypeScriptCompile Remove="ClientApp\node_modules\**" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

8. Basically you have to exclude node_modules, match `tsconfig.json` to the config in you `csproj` file like above and you wont see intellisense errors anymore.

Comment: Can someone tell me if prettier can be used with Visual Studio 2019 on windows? My co-worker uses VS and I use VS Code with Prettier and those huge 4 space indentions don't look good and we get merge issues because of it. I'd like to use the same formatter and have him get on board, but he likes VS (not VS Code)?

Comment: @MattoMK There is no prettier formatter for VS2019 buy you can use editorconfig to setup cross-ide coding standards https://editorconfig.org/

VS2019 supports editorconfig and there is a plugin for VSCode too